# Should I create separate users for glassfish, mysql or not?

Tags: installation, server

I recently installed Ubuntu Server and now I am reading about it. I am going to install software and I see many tutorials create a own user for each program and a group. I am going to install `Glassfish`, `MySQL` etc and I wonder if these should have their own users such as glassfish user, mysql user and so on? Or is it sufficient/better to just create a group and add my own nonroot account to it?

Answer (score 1):

**Glassfish** or **MySQL** will create their own users and I think it's better to rely on them instead of creating a group and adding your **non-root** user to it.

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu, applications come in a form of *packages* which are stored in a *package repository* and installed using a *package manager*. A package normally comes with install scripts, config files and everything needed to run the particular software, including creating and configuring non-privileged user accounts.

You normally should not be concerned with creating user accounts for your MySQL server, manually compiling programs or even creating config files, especially if you're new to Linux. As @KetanPatel suggests, just use `sudo apt-get install (package name)` if you have terminal access; or use Software Center if you have GUI.

Comment: Why the downvote?